# Android Package Manager App Icons Memory Usage

Tags: android

I'm getting installed applications using this code

```
Intent appsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
appsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
return this.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(appsIntent, 0);
```

And, I'm loading application icons in recyclerview adapter using this

```
holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(resolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
```

But, if user have a lot of application, app crashing with memory exception. And, i used android:largeHeap="true" but i want low memory usage. I can't use glide library because it can't load drawable object. What can i do?

Comment: please post your recycle view adapter code , i think your recycle is not recycling .

Comment: i haven't problem in adapter. Icons loading successfully. But it using 80-150 mb memory @mhdjazmati

Comment: that's why you ARE having a problem , your issue that your recycle view isn't recycling !

you could cecke that by adding Log.d("something",adapter.getpostion);
inside your onBindViewHolder and see if it loads all your items